# Getting max date from a joined table with group by

Tags: mysql, group-by, max

I've got 3 tables - `entryrecord`, `employee` and `employee_entryrecord` (linking table).

The query I'd like is for it to return the most recent (`max time`) `inout` record for each employee.

```
employee
id employee
1  John
2  Tom

entryrecord
id created_date       inout
1 2016-07-22 16:01:38 1
2 2016-07-22 16:03:22 1
3 2016-07-22 16:05:22 2
4 2016-07-22 16:07:22 2
5 2016-07-22 16:09:22 1


I'd like the follow output
created_date         employee  inout  entryrecordid
2016-07-22 16:09:22  John       1       5
2016-07-22 16:05:22  Tom        2       3
```

However, in the sqlfiddle below you can see it does not return the correct `inout` and `entryrecordid` values.

I've created a sqlfiddle to view what I've done.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/89b53/6/0)

Any help would be great.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please give it a try:

```
SELECT
finalALias.created_date,
E.employee,
finalALias.inout,
finalALias.id AS entryrecordid
FROM employee E

INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
    *
    FROM entryrecord entryR 
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT
          EER.employeeid,
          MAX(created_date) max_time
        FROM entryrecord ER
        INNER JOIN employee_entryrecord EER ON ER.id = EER.entryrecordid
        GROUP BY EER.employeeid
    ) t 
    ON t.max_time=entryR.created_date
) AS finalALias
ON E.id = finalALias.employeeid
ORDER BY finalALias.created_date DESC;
```

<kbd>[**WORKING DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/89b53/13/0)</kbd>

*Just a gentle reminder:*

`E -> employee`

`ER -> entryrecord`

`ERR -> employee_entryrecord`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that grouping happens before ordering. You will have to do a sub query. You always want to try and keep your sub queries to a minimum as they put a heavy toll on the SQL server.

I changed your LEFT JOINS to INNER JOINS because it looked like you wanted to only get employees that were in the other tables.

```
SELECT 
    entryrecord.created_date, 
    employee.employee, 
    entryrecord.inout,
    entryrecord.id 
FROM 
    entryrecord 
INNER JOIN 
    employee_entryrecord ON entryrecord.id = employee_entryrecord.entryrecordid 
INNER JOIN 
    employee ON employee_entryrecord.employeeid = employee.id 
WHERE 
    entryrecord.inout in (1,2) 
    AND entryrecord.id = (
        SELECT er2.id 
        FROM employee_entryrecord eer2, entryrecord er2 
        WHERE eer2.employeeid = employee.id 
        AND er2.id = eer2.entryrecordid 
        ORDER BY er2.created_date DESC LIMIT 1
    )
```